# writing data to csv in jmeter and reusing same csv each time

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have to crawl price data of some site each day and i want to store each day data in same csv but in different column with date on top .I am using .csv file to write the data but each day it is overwriting the existing data and not changing the column.I want to write data as shown in image-:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6O9E.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CSV is the right format for you, it's better to go for [XLSX](https://www.howtogeek.com/392333/what-is-an-xlsx-file-and-how-do-i-open-one/) and [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) library for creating/updating excel file.

1. Add [tika-app.jar](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. When you need to create/update Excel file - add the relevant [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and use the following reference code:

   ```
   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell
   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook

   XSSFWorkbook workbook
   XSSFSheet sheet
   XSSFRow row

   File excelFile = new File("/path/to/your/file.xlsx")
   if (!excelFile.exists()) {
       workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()
       sheet = workbook.createSheet()
       row = sheet.createRow(0)
       Cell firstCell = row.createCell(0)
       firstCell.setCellValue(new Date().format("dd/MM/yyyy"))
       Row row2 = sheet.createRow(1)
       Cell secondsCell = row2.createCell(0)
       secondsCell.setCellValue("a")
       //etc
       workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(excelFile))

   } else {
       FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(excelFile)
       workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream)
       sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0)
       row = sheet.getRow(0)
       Cell firstCell = row.createCell(row.getLastCellNum())
       firstCell.setCellValue(new Date().format("dd/MM/yyyy"))
       Row row2 = sheet.getRow(1)
       Cell secondCell = row2.createCell(row2.getLastCellNum())
       secondCell.setCellValue("s")
       //etc
       inputStream.close()
       FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(excelFile)
       workbook.write(outputStream)
       outputStream.close()

   }
   ```

More information:

- [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](http://Apache%20Groovy%20-%20Why%20and%20How%20You%20Should%20Use%20It)